# PostgreSQL. Как остановить процесс бэкапа в pqAdmin4

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, резервное-копирование

Имеется PostgreSQL. Запустил процесс бэкапа базы с помощью pqAdmin4.
В итоге уже 2 недели вижу вот такие окошки в правой нижней части (как на первом скриншоте). Никак не могу избавиться от них.

Если нажму на ссылку **Click here for details** то тоже нет ничего такого, чтобы остановить процесс и убрать эти окошки.

Подскажите, как остановить и убрать их?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Вероятно это баг pgAdmin. [Здесь](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/155727/sql-command-to-clean-job-queue-in-pgadmin-4?rq=1) человек столкнулся с аналогичной проблемой и утверждает, что удаление `pgadmin.db` из `C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\pgAdmin` помогло, но потребует повторного ввода паролей и т.п.

Comment: Спасибо, это решило проблему!